# Word for accept or refuse a request

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrase-requests

Ok, a user receives a partnership request from another user and can either accept or refuse it.

Is there a word for that? I mean, a word to indicate the action of taking a decision about it without information on the kind of decision.

Accept, ratify, etc.. indicate a positive response while refuse, discard, etc.. indicate a negative response, I need something neutral/generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

> Resolve, settle, decide, determine

Regarding resolve, the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resolve) suggest as meaning:

> 1. Settle or find a solution to (a problem or contentious matter)
> 2. Decide firmly on a course of action.

Regarding settle, the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/settle) suggests as meaning:

> 1. Resolve or reach an agreement about (an argument or problem)

So both point to each other.